# Template10: AppBarButton: Content with TextBox is not allowing user to input space

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, template10

I am getting a weird issue with the template10 (https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) when I am trying to put a TextBox in the AppBarButton element the space key is not working (when you press the space key nothing happens you need to wait 3/4 seconds before it starts working).  However every other key is working...

Anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Here is the simple XAML code:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Find" Visibility="Visible">
    <AppBarButton.Content>
        <TextBox Width="100" />
     </AppBarButton.Content>
</AppBarButton>
```

I get the same issue with:

```
 <AppBarButton Visibility="Visible">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <TextBox Width="100" />
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
```

@Chris W:
Is this what you want me to try? it seems a but odd to add a popup element no?

```
<AppBarButton Visibility="Visible" Width="100">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <Popup IsOpen="True" >
                        <TextBox Width="100" />
                    </Popup>
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
```

Comment: So from [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.aspx) - **The Content property is ignored if the Icon is set.** So I'm not sure what the caveat is here, what about plopping it in an attached PopUp instead of as Content?

Comment: I have updated my post, however I get the same issue even if I don't set the Icon property

Comment: BTW: your idea of putting it in a popup does work thanks =)

Comment: Yea I'm not entirely sure how to answer this one, haven't ran into the issue before. I'd have to load up a uwp proj to fiddle around to see what the result's are visually. Hence the comment lol.

Comment: it works its not sexy but it works =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is a strange idea when the `Content` property is available to you. But, hey, you are the developer and you know your app. Not me.

Okay, the problem is because the `AppBarButton` clearly catches the space and handles it. You can overcome this with this simple approach:

```
<controls:PageHeader Content="Main Page">
    <AppBarButton Width="250" Padding="0">
        <AppBarButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox Width="250" Height="32" Margin="0,8,0,0"
                            KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </AppBarButton.Template>
    </AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Find" />
</controls:PageHeader>
```

And then this handler:

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Space)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        textBox.SelectionStart = (textBox.Text += " ").Length;
    }
}
```

Works like a charm:

[image]

Best of luck!

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.